# Copying underscore's chain method style

Tags: javascript, oop, object, chaining

In the function `cat` below you can call the `eat` and `play` functions directly without instantiating a new `cat` object, this is demonstrated by passing in the value from the function `cat.eat` into the `cat.play` function to get the status.

```
var cat = function(obj){
  // if (obj instanceof cat) return obj;
  // if (!(this instanceof cat)) return new cat(obj);
  // this.catwrapped = obj;
}

cat.eat = function(food){
  if(food == "tuna") return 95
  if(food == "milk") return 35
  return 0
}

cat.play = function(energy){
  if(energy < 50) return 0
  return 100
}

var energy  = cat.eat("tuna")
var status = cat.play(energy)

console.log(status) // 100
```

I'm trying to keep this functionality and add underscore style chaining. So you can do the following. How is this acchieved?

```
cat.day = function(obj){
  var instance = cat(obj);
  // instance._chain = true;
  return instance;
}

var status = cat.day()
  .eat("tuna")
  .play()
  .status()

console.log(status) // should log 100
```

What's the minimum code that I need to have in `cat` and `cat.day` to make this work?

Comment: Woah, just found that [underscore loops over itself](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1550) to create all the `prototypes`.

Comment: I think I was wrong here it's just adding the array operations to the underscore library.

Comment: Are your functions *doing* anything? If they have no side effects, you can completely omit calls to them. Shouldn't they at least mutate the cat instance? Currently, your functions only return some number. The next function returns a different number, there is nothing that relates them. Chaining seems quite useless here.

Comment: @Bergi The thing that relates them is that they're chained, just like underscore. The previous functions value is piped into the next function. That's what underscore does, and it products much more legible call then returning values for each function. [Here's a primer on underscore chaining.](http://www.miniarray.com/chaining-in-underscore/)

Comment: No, that's what I'm pointing at: There is nothing to pipe in your example functions. Your functions do neither return cats on which methods could be called at, nor do they return results that could be passed as arguments to the next function.

Comment: Oh, wait, I somehow missed that you pass the `energy` from the `eat` call into the `play` call. However your `day` function doesn't seem to pass anything into `eat`, does it?

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't realize that when I was thinking this up. In my answer I pass the `food` variable to `chain()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a npm module [`underscore-chainable`](https://github.com/reggi/underscore-chainable) to do just this.

```
npm install underscore-chainable
```

Then

```
var _ = require("underscore")
_.mixin(require("underscore-chainable"))

var cat = _.makeChainable() // make the `cat` object chainable

cat.eat = function(food){
  if(food == "tuna") return 95
  if(food == "milk") return 35
  return 0
}

cat.play = function(energy){
  if(energy < 50) return 0
  return 100
}

_.extendChainable(cat) // extend the chainablity

// adds `.chain` and `.value`

var energy  = cat.eat("tuna")
var status = cat.play(energy)

console.log(status) // 100

var status = cat
  .chain("tuna")
  .eat()
  .play()
  .value()

console.log(status) // 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return pointer of the object to be able to perform a chain calls:

```
cat.play = function(energy){
  // do something with energy
  return cat
}

cat.eat = function(food){
  // do something with food
  return cat
}

var status = cat.day()
   .eat("tuna")
   .play()
   .status()
```

Since you using return for different purpose (and ignoring it after) you need to reconsider your program algorithm

Update. You can create a function what will perform a task or return data depending from a parameter:

```
var energy = 0;
cat.eat = function(v) {
    // return something on empty call
    if (!arguments.length) return energy 
    // process passed data
    energy += v
    // return cat object to allow chaincals
    return cat
}
```

In this case cat.eat(10) will allow you to perform a chain call, while cat.eat() will return you value, stored in energy

Update2: Your functions does not alter any internal variables, so any data will be lost in a standart chain call. What you do, you need a pipe and direct output of one function to another input. There are numbers of way how to do it:

You can try and use underscore reduce function:

```
var status = _.reduce([cat.play, cat.eat], function(status, f){ return f(status); }, "tuna");
```

Or you can call them directly:

```
cat.status(cat.play(cat.eat("tuna")))
```

If you create internal variable to store energy, you even can call underscore chain:

```
var cat = function() {
  this.energy = 0; 
}

cat.eat = function(food){
  if (food == "tuna") cat.energy = 95
  else if(food == "milk") cat.energy = 35
  else cat.energy = 0
}

cat.play = function(){
  if(cat.energy < 50) cat.energy = 0
  else cat.energy = 100
}

var status = _.chain(cat)
   .eat("tuna")
   .play()
   .value()
   .energy
```

but it seems a bit redundant

Comment: Underscore doesn't return `this`, or `_` or `cat` at the end of each function call, because it should return the value of the operation. I found that it creates all the prototypes that do programatically.

Comment: You will have to copy all the method into a new cat object :S, and also the result

Comment: Each underscore function doesn't seem to copy anything it just [seems to return the result](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L520-L522).

Comment: I just want each function to return a value, and be chain-able. I don't want the chanablity dependent on if there's an argument. That's a sloppy way to craft functions.

Comment: You can not make a chain call to a function what return a value. To be able to do so, the function MUST return an object. That is a JavaScript rules. Could you please post an example of underscore function calls you are referring, so I could get a picture, what pattern you are creating.

Comment: BTW The functions you currently have (eat and play) does not make a sense to call in a chain. You do not modify any public or internal variables and do not process the results of the functions either, Even if you do chain-call them somehow, the result will be lost.

Comment: @Dmitry There is a way. I'm missing the `.status()` method (equivalent to underscores `.value`) in these examples but my desired result is possible. Here's what I've got. https://gist.github.com/reggi/d3db86e0149c16fb99a9

Comment: @ThomasReggi yes and your chainResult function does exactly what I have suggested. It return an object to make chan-call possible.

Answer (score 0):

I copied out the all of underscores functions that make it chain-able and I added it to the end of the object.

The idea is you can create functions that behave like normal functions, perform some kind of input / output operation. Then you can loop over all of these functions and build the prototypes involved in making an object chain-able, like storing data and transferring arguments.

```
var _ = require("underscore")

var cat = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof cat) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof cat)) return new cat(obj);
  this._wrapped = obj;
};

cat.eat = function(food){
  if(food == "tuna") return 95
  if(food == "milk") return 35
  return 0
}

cat.play = function(energy){
  if(energy < 50) return 0
  return 100
}

// Add a "chain" function. Start chaining a wrapped Underscore object.
cat.chain = function(obj) {
  var instance = cat(obj);
  instance._chain = true;
  return instance;
};

// Helper function to continue chaining intermediate results.
var chainResult = function(instance, obj) {
  return instance._chain ? cat(obj).chain() : obj;
};

var ArrayProto = Array.prototype
var push = ArrayProto.push

cat.mixin = function(obj) {
  _.each(_.functions(obj), function(name) {
    var func = cat[name] = obj[name];
    cat.prototype[name] = function() {
      var args = [this._wrapped];
      push.apply(args, arguments);
      return chainResult(this, func.apply(cat, args));
    };
  });
};

// Add all of the Underscore functions to the wrapper object.
cat.mixin(cat);

// Extracts the result from a wrapped and chained object.
cat.prototype.value = function() {
  return this._wrapped;
};


// var energy  = cat.eat("tuna")
// var status = cat.play(energy)
//
// console.log(status) // 100

var status = cat.chain("tuna")
  .eat()
  .play()
  .value()

console.log(status) // 100
```

UPDATE:

I made the functions to make any object a chainable object a underscore mixin.

Here's the mixin:

```
var _ = require("underscore")

_.mixin({
  prototypeChain: function(thObj){
    return function(obj) {
      var instance = thObj(obj);
      instance._chain = true;
      return instance;
    }
  },
  prototypeExtend: function(theObj){
    var chainResult = function(instance, obj) {
      return instance._chain ? theObj(obj).chain() : obj;
    }
    var prototypes = _.map(_.functions(theObj), function(name) {
      var func = theObj[name];
      theObj.prototype[name] = function() {
        var args = [this._wrapped];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(args, arguments);
        return chainResult(this, func.apply(theObj, args));
      };
    });
    _.extend(theObj, prototypes)
  },
  prototypeValue: function(){
    return function(){
      return this._wrapped;
    }
  }
})
```

Here's how it works:

```
var cat = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof cat) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof cat)) return new cat(obj);
  this._wrapped = obj;
};

cat.eat = function(food){
  if(food == "tuna") return 95
  if(food == "milk") return 35
  return 0
}

cat.play = function(energy){
  if(energy < 50) return 0
  return 100
}

cat.chain = _.prototypeChain(cat)
_.prototypeExtend(cat)
cat.prototype.value = _.prototypeValue()

var energy  = cat.eat("tuna")
var status = cat.play(energy)

console.log(status) // 100

var status = cat.chain("tuna")
  .eat()
  .play()
  .value()

console.log(status) // 100
```